# Как в TextField при вводе автоматически разделять пробелом тысячи?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Пользователь вводит числа в TextField. Как отделять визуально при этом тысячи, миллионы итд?... "15 000", "150 000", "1 500 000"?

И как потом производить операции исчисления с такими числами?

Comment: Добрый день, 
посмотрите на ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412491/realtime-formatting-with-nsnumberformatter-in-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

нужно пользоваться UITextFieldDelegate

```
 - textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

в нем ты сможешь разделить строку как тебе надо

если лень самому можешь юзать
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/reformattednumberfield